# Why does gRPC throw an "established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" every second on windows only?

Tags: java, netty, grpc, grpc-java

On Windows *only*, I have a grpc server that throws this INFO-level stack trace every second:

```
2017-10-09T20:11:00,366 - INFO  - [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-13:io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport:grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport@159] - {} - Transport failed
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288) ~[    ]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1106) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.14.Final.jar:4.1.14.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:372) ~[netty-transport-4.1.14.Final.jar:4.1.14.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123) [netty-transport-4.1.14.Final.jar:4.1.14.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) [netty-transport-4.1.14.Final.jar:4.1.14.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) [netty-transport-4.1.14.Final.jar:4.1.14.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) [netty-transport-4.1.14.Final.jar:4.1.14.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) [netty-transport-4.1.14.Final.jar:4.1.14.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.14.Final.jar:4.1.14.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138) [netty-common-4.1.14.Final.jar:4.1.14.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

This may be the same thing logged in https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1768

Once again, I get this error on Windows only!

The app seems to function OK regardless of this issue.

When I start a simple "hello world" application with a io.grpc.Server, I do not see this INFO stack trace.

But when I use my real application which opens up a bi-directional http2 streaming connection between a grpc server and a jetty server that stays open for the duration of the application... i get this message once-per-second flooding my logs.

Is it safe to turn `NettyServerTransport` logging to `WARN` level? Or should I worry about the frequency of this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this message is coming about because of a tcp heartbeat checker on a third party java application that we use watching to see if my service is up.

It makes an `InetSocketAddress(ip, port)` request to check to see if the http2 port is still responding.

Every time it does this (only on Windows) it dumps out that annoying stack trace. Looking into why.

Issue created: https://github.com/nddipiazza/grpc-java-bidirectional-streaming-example